# Is there a way to dynamically partition a PostgresSQL table for each month?

Tags: sql, postgresql, liquibase, partitioning, database-partitioning

I have a large table that I need to partition based on a date field and the partitions will each be one month. Like so:

```
create table my_schema.my_table_202210 partition of my_schema.my_table
    for values from ('2022-10-01 00:00:00') to ('2022-11-01 00:00:00');
alter table my_schema.my_table_202210
    owner to my_owner;

create table my_schema.my_table_202211 partition of my_schema.my_table
    for values from ('2022-11-01 00:00:00') to ('2022-12-01 00:00:00');
alter table my_schema.my_table_202211
    owner to my_owner;
```

As you can see, with this method I need a partition statement for each month. Is there some way to do this dynamically so I do not need to use static dates and multiple statements?
With this method I can only put so many dates here and even if I go out 2 or 3 years I will still need to remember to come back before the last partitioned date and add more statements here to keep my app running. I'm using Liquibase to create and handle my database schema.

Comment: See [pg_partman](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks, this looks useful. Unfortunately I don't think my organization will allow the use of this. Was hoping there would be something native to Postgres that would allow me to do this.

Comment: 1) It is Postgres extension so I would consider it native. 2) If you are talking about the core code partitioning as documented here [Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html) then there is not. You would have to use something like a `cron` job to do this.

Comment: There is no built-in solution for that.